# Jquery onchange appendTo not working inside modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to implement append inside a modal. I succeed on getting the value of the select using get request following this code

```
    $('#xservice').change(function() {
    var select = $("#sampleDoc").empty();
    let x = $('#xdate').empty();
    console.log(select);
    console.log("Sample");
    $.get('api.php', {service: $('#xservice').val(),date: $('#xdate').val(), time: $("#xtime").val()}, function(result) {
        $.each(result, function(i, item) {
            console.log(item);
            $("<option value=" + item.value + ">" + item.name + "</option>").
            appendTo(select);
        });
    });
});
```

Console has this response
[image]

Here's my view code

```
        <select name="sampleDoc" id="sampleDoc" class="form-control" required>
              <option value="" selected>-- Please Select -- </option>
          </select>
```

So whenever i try the onchange function the console is successfully logging in and there's a successful result, but the select is not changing or the value isn't passed at all.

Comment: Does not make any sense.... `let x = $('#xdate').empty();` and than right after that you read the value of it `date: $('#xdate').val(),`

Comment: Code above should work. what is different here versus your real code? Is `console.log(select);` showing the select element?

Comment: console.log has the value of returned data from php but is not appending to the select

Answer (score 0):

You are mistake to append the Item thing you are generate inside your result

Try this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="xservice" id="xservice" class="form-control" required>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
</select>

<select name="sampleDoc" id="sampleDoc" class="form-control" required>
   <option value="" selected>-- Please Select -- </option>
</select>

$('#xservice').change(function() {
    var select = $("#sampleDoc").empty();
    let x = $('#xdate').empty();
    console.log(select);
    console.log("Sample");
    $.get('api.php', {service: $('#xservice').val(),date: $('#xdate').val(), time: $("#xtime").val()}, function(result) {
        $('#sampleDoc').append('<option value="" selected>-- Please Select -- </option>');
        $.each(result, function(i, item) {
            $('#sampleDoc').append($("<option value=" + item.value + ">" + item.name + "</option>"));
        });
    });
});
```

**Don't Forget to add the jquery.js before you call any jquery code**

Comment: it's not working. same with the thing i tried there's no result in the selection

Comment: I tried it and it's not working.I'm really confused now why it's not working at all when it's inside a modal but working when it is on a separate form.

Answer (score 0):

> **Edited:**
>   Now you can test the working example here and follow the same way on your API as well.

You have to append for this element `#sampleDoc`, also the value should be covered with `""`

```js
$('#xservice').change(function() {

    var select = $("#sampleDoc").empty();
    
    //let x = $('#xdate').empty();
    //console.log(select);
    //console.log("Sample");
    
    $.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2', {
    
        service: $('#xservice').val(),
        date: $('#xdate').val(),
        time: $("#xtime").val()
        
    }, function(result) {
        
        var data = result.data;
        
        //console.log(data);
        
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        
            console.log(item.first_name);
        
            var text = '<option value="' + item.id + '">' + item.first_name + '</option>';
                    
            $("#sampleDoc").append(text);
        
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="xservice" id="xservice" class="form-control" required>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
</select>

<select name="sampleDoc" id="sampleDoc" class="form-control" required>
   <option value="" selected>-- Please Select -- </option>
</select>
```

Comment: @kiogipaya I've edited my answer with working example you can follow the way

Comment: I followed everything and still not working properly. :(